# why does $\frac{b\partial a}{a \partial b} = \frac{\partial \log a}{\partial \log b}$?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling, physics

I am doing some background research on sensitivity and elasticity analysis, and I came across the following [definitions of elasticity](http://www.ag.unr.edu/sedinger/Courses/ERS488-688/lectures/ers485lecture10.pdf):

$$e_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}\partial \lambda}{\lambda \partial a_{ij}}$$

$$e_{ij} = \frac{\partial \log \lambda}{\partial \log a_{ij}}$$

Why are these equivalent?

Comment: According to the linked-to document, you have $\partial$ (`\partial`), not $\delta$ (`\delta`).

Comment: Notice that the formula in your title is wrong...

Comment: @Arturo thanks. I had searched for the latex symbol under 'del' instead of 'partial'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Chain Rule:
$$\frac{\partial\log\lambda}{\partial \log a_{ij}}\;\frac{\partial\log a_{ij}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial\log\lambda}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial t}.$$
Since $$\frac{\partial\log a_{ij}}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{a_{ij}}\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial t}$$
"solving" for $\frac{\partial\log\lambda}{\partial \log a_{ij}}$ gives
$$\frac{\partial\log\lambda}{\partial\log a_{ij}} = \frac{\quad\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}\quad}{\frac{1}{a_{ij}}\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial t}} = \frac{a_{ij}\partial \lambda}{\lambda\partial a_{ij}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Because $\partial \log x=\frac{\partial x}{x}$, whatever it is that $\partial$ may mean.

Comment: See the edit I just made; the source has $\partial$, not $\delta$.

Comment: thanks for reminding me of the rule, however, I still don't understand the rationale.

Comment: @David: the rationale is that it is true... You can justify it using the chain rule, for example. If that is what you want to ask, then ask that :)